How To Decrypt a .p7m File via Python
I have a make.com automation, that iterates over emails and downloads the Attachment files. Now I want to decrypt the files of emails that are p7m type.
I have a key like this "Lieferant_9984366000006(private).key" with content like this:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

and a certificate "9900683000008_ssl_certificate.cert" file like this with this content:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

and on top of that of course the smime.p7m file with the encrypted content. I'm not able to find something useful to this topic.
This is my code which is not working:
import os
from OpenSSL import crypto

# Define paths
RECEIVER_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = 'Lieferant_9984366000006(privat).key'
SENDER_CERTIFICATES_DIR = 'sender_certs'
ENCRYPTED_FILES_DIR = 'p7m_files'
DECRYPTED_FILES_DIR = 'decrypted_files'

# Load receiver's private key
def load_private_key(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as key_file:
        private_key = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key_file.read())
    return private_key

# Load sender's certificate
def load_certificate(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as cert_file:
        certificate = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert_file.read())
    return certificate

# Decrypt a single file
def decrypt_file(encrypted_file, decrypted_file, private_key, certificate):
    with open(encrypted_file, 'rb') as f:
        encrypted_data = f.read()

    # Create a PKCS7 object from the encrypted data
    pkcs7 = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, encrypted_data)

    # Create BIOs for input and output
    bio_in = crypto._new_mem_buf(encrypted_data)
    bio_out = crypto._new_mem_buf()

    # Decrypt the PKCS7 data
    if not crypto.PKCS7_decrypt(pkcs7, private_key, certificate, bio_out):
        raise ValueError("Decryption failed")

    # Read the decrypted data from the output BIO
    decrypted_data = crypto._bio_to_string(bio_out)

    with open(decrypted_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(decrypted_data)

def main():
    private_key = load_private_key(RECEIVER_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)

    for file_name in os.listdir(ENCRYPTED_FILES_DIR):
        if file_name.endswith('.p7m'):
            # Extract sender code from the file name
            sender_code = file_name.split('__')[1].split('_')[0]
            sender_cert_path = os.path.join(SENDER_CERTIFICATES_DIR, f'{sender_code}_ssl_certificate.crt')

            if os.path.exists(sender_cert_path):
                certificate = load_certificate(sender_cert_path)
                encrypted_file_path = os.path.join(ENCRYPTED_FILES_DIR, file_name)
                decrypted_file_path = os.path.join(DECRYPTED_FILES_DIR, file_name.replace('.p7m', '.txt'))

                try:
                    decrypt_file(encrypted_file_path, decrypted_file_path, private_key, certificate)
                    print(f'Successfully decrypted {file_name}')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Failed to decrypt {file_name}: {e}')
            else:
                print(f'Certificate for sender code {sender_code} not found.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71066064/11355926 - alternatively, call openssl via subprocess, see more here (for ssl cmd): https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90811/decrypting-p7m-file-with-key-pem-using-openssl
